# How to add a new language (compiler) to G-WAN?

Tags: g-wan, freebasic

Is it possible (and if yes, how) to add new compiled languages to G-WAN such as Free Basic (fbc) and Basic 4 QT (Q7BCompiler) which both provide complete IDE and build Linux executables?

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

A competent C programmer could call these BASIC runtimes from a G-WAN handler. But if there's sufficient interest then the best integration option is to contact the G-WAN team.